# Is there a way to initialize android espresso tests as a list of tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-automation

I have 2 android espresso tests to validate my UI. Say, testA() and testB(). testA() adds a list of items and verify if items have added successfully and then sign out of application. 
testB() adds list of items, verifies items added then edits the items and verify. If successful, sign out of application. 
Here if you look at it, testB() is repeating all the steps in testA() and performing some additional steps. I am trying to see if there is a way to initialize(maybe during setUp() method) tests as elements in a list. 
So in this case after items added successfully in testA(), the test is a pass and then start testB() from that point instead of quit the app, relaunch and repeat testA() then do additional steps specific to testB().

My code looks something like this:

```
@get:Rule var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false) @Before @Throws(Exception::class) open fun setUp() { activityRule.launchActivity(null) }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try not to have dependent tests. Each and every test should be able to pass, no matter if you run them all or just some individually.

What you're looking for is most likely to create a `setUp()` method that is run before every test, that sets up your mocked test data. Annotate it with `@Before` to ensure that it's run before every test.

Comment: I have my rule and setUp method as below and is run before every test. I am not sure on what should I initialize inside setUp method.
`@get:Rule
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)
@Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    open fun setUp() {
        activityRule.launchActivity(null)
    }`

Comment: @chaitanya, it would help if you could edit your question above and add your current code there, and then we can have another look.